# Is there a way to open HTML revealjs slides in VS Code?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, reveal.js

I am giving a presentation in which I need to have my code editor open alongside my HTML slides. Since I have the VS Code editor configured the way I need, it would be nice to have a way to display the HTML slides in the VS Code editor itself.

I strongly suspect this is possible, because VS Code is a very powerful editor with several extensions and features. I have tried installing an HTML previewer from the marketplace, but that could not load all the dynamic content of the slides. I also tried the [VS Code reveal](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=evilz.vscode-reveal) extension, but that did not work for me either.

Is there an alternative way to do this? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[Live Server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer) VS Code add-on launch a local development server with live reload feature for static & dynamic pages; the reveal presentation is automatically rendered each time the edited code is saved on the VS Code side (Control+S).

There is an [unreleased version](https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-server-plus-plus) yet that does not require saving  to see the changes...truly live.

It is a workflow that makes it much easier to check changes before publishing them. Combined with the possibility of editing the html front-end of the presentation generated by Live Server, with the browser's Dev Tools, a very dynamic environment is created.